# Prevent focus to shift to another widget when tab key is pressed, Instead it suppose to add space in text input

Tags: flutter, tabs, focus, desktop, space

How can I modify my text editor for Windows (desktop) to prevent the focus from being shifted to another widget? For instance, when I press the Tab key, instead of the focus moving from the text input to a button, I would like to incorporate a tab space within the text field itself.

I am building a text editor.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:adaptive_theme/adaptive_theme.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
// import 'package:flutter_highlight_textfield/flutter_highlight_textfield.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TextEditorApp());
}

class TextEditorApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextEditorApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AdaptiveTheme(
      light: ThemeData.light(useMaterial3: true),
      dark: ThemeData.dark(useMaterial3: true),
      initial: AdaptiveThemeMode.light,
      builder: (theme, darkTheme) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Simple Text Editor',
          theme: theme,
          darkTheme: darkTheme,
          home: const TextEditor(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class TextEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextEditor({super.key});

  @override
  State<TextEditor> createState() => _TextEditorState();
}

class _TextEditorState extends State<TextEditor> {
  late TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _saveTextAsFile(String text) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${directory.path}/text_file.txt');
    await file.writeAsString(text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Simple Text Editor'),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              String? selectedDirectory = await FilePicker.platform.saveFile(
                dialogTitle: 'Save file',
                type: FileType.custom,
                allowedExtensions: ['txt'],
              );
              if (selectedDirectory == null) {
                // User canceled the picker
                return;
              } else {
                String filePath = '$selectedDirectory.txt';
                File file = File(filePath);
                String text = _controller.text;
                await file.writeAsString(text);
              }
            },
            child: const Text('Save'),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                dialogTitle: 'Save file',
                type: FileType.custom,
                allowedExtensions: ['txt'],
              );

              if (result != null) {
                PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
                String? filePath = file.path;
                if (filePath != null) {
                  File pickedFile = File(filePath);
                  String text = await pickedFile.readAsString();
                  debugPrint(text);
                  _controller.text = text;
                }
              } else {
                // User canceled the picker
              }
            },
            child: const Text('Open'),
          ),
          Switch(
            value: AdaptiveTheme.of(context).mode.isDark,
            onChanged: (value) {
              AdaptiveTheme.of(context).toggleThemeMode();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          maxLines: null,
          expands: true,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            labelText: 'Start typing...',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use focus node but it doesn't seems to work.